# Update Cursor from TEXT to DATE field

Tags: arcpy, cursor, date

I have column that contains dates that are created from a numpy array to fc, since numpy doesn't handle date types I have had to create another field to update the rows.  When using this script in the ArcPy window, no errors are returned, however my values do not change for `UPDATE_DATE_DATE`.  What could cause this?

UPDATE_DATE_DATE is a DATE type field while OPEN_TIME is a string type field.  And I would like to set the string values as DATE type in UPDATE_DATE_DATE.

Here is an example of the date format for `OPEN_TIME`, 9/25/2015 12:29:04 AM.

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue("UPDATE_DATE_DATE", row.getValue("OPEN_TIME"))
cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your dates? There are many date formats.

Comment: Following @EmilBrundage 's comment, the `cursor.updateRow(row)` command appears to be out-of-loop, like it may only execute on the last row.

Comment: @Jim I think you should create an answer from your comment.  It will only need to be expanded a little.  I just fell for a similar trap of forgetting to include an `updateRow` and seeing no change to my data.

Answer (score 1):

The call to the `cursor.updateRow(row)` method appears to be out-of-loop in the code snippet provided. Given the code snippet, I'm thinking `cursor.updateRow(row)` would only execute once, after exiting the `for` loop. Indenting the `cursor.updateRow(row)` as follows should fix it:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    row.setValue("UPDATE_DATE_DATE", row.getValue("OPEN_TIME"))
    cursor.updateRow(row) # Indent added here.
```